A system of equations of power sums for 3 variables
I am currently interested in the following problem:

Find $x, y, z$ such that
$$
\begin{cases} 
x + y + z = 2 \\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6 \\
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8
\end{cases}
$$

I noticed how the solutions would be symmetric over $x, y, z$ (which means that if $(x, y, z) = (a, b, c)$ is an solution then so does $(x, y, z) = \text{any permutation of } (a, b, c)$
Therefore, in order to solve this problem, I defined $s = x + y$ and $p = xy$. From there, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
s + z = 2 \ (1)\\ 
s^2 - 2p + z^2 = 6 \ (2)\\
s^3 - 3ps + z^3 = 8 \ (3) 
\end{cases}
$$
Substituting $z = 2 - s$ into the second and third equations:
$$
(2) \Rightarrow s^2 - 2p + (2 - s)^2 = 6 \Rightarrow s^2 - 2p + s^2 - 4s + 4 = 6  \\
\Rightarrow 2s^2 - 4s - 2p = 2 \Rightarrow s^2 - 2s - p = 1 \ (4)
$$
$$
(3) \Rightarrow s^3 - 3ps + (2 - s)^3 = 8 \Rightarrow s^3 - 3ps + 8 -12s + 6s^2 - s^3 = 8 \\
\Rightarrow 6s^2 -12s - 3ps = 0 \Rightarrow 3s(2s - 4 - p) = 0 \ (5)
$$
From equation $(5)$, we have either $s = 0$ or $s = \frac{p + 4}{2}$. Substituting this result into other equations, we have:
$$
s = 0 \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x = -y\\
z = 2 \ (\text{because of eq. 1}) \\ 
p = -1 = -x^2  \Rightarrow x = \pm 1 \Rightarrow y = \mp 1
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow (2, 1, -1) \text{ and all its permutations are solutions.}
$$
$$s = \frac{p + 4}{2} \Rightarrow \left(\frac{p + 4}{2}\right)^2 - 2\frac{p + 4}{2} -p = 1 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{p^2 + 8p + 16}{4} - (p + 4) - p = 1 \Rightarrow p^2 + 8p + 16 - 4(2p + 4) = 4 \\ \Rightarrow p^2 = 4 \Rightarrow p = \pm 2$$
If $p = 2$ then $s = 3$ and $x, y$ would the solutions of $x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0 \Rightarrow (x, y ) = (1, 2)$ or $(x, y) = (2, 1)$ and $z = 2 - s = -1 \Rightarrow$ the solution is $(2, 1, -1)$ and its permutations.
If $p = -2$ then $s = 1$ and $x, y$ are solutions of $x^2 - x - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow (x, y) = (-1, 2)$ or $(x, y) = (2, -1)$ and $z = 2 - s = 1$, so we are back at $(2, 1, 1)$ again.
I want to know if my solution is correct and are there any simpler ways to tackle this problem, especially for how (tediously) long my solution is. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

HINT
If $\alpha = x + y + z$, $\beta = xy + xz + yz$ and $\gamma = xyz$, the proposed system of equations becomes:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\alpha = 2\\\\
\alpha^{2} - 2\beta = 6\\\\
\alpha^{3} - 3\alpha\beta + 3\gamma = 8
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

this is so stupidly simple compared to the massive solution I did above, thanks!

Embrace the power of symmetric polynomials.

I did, just in a much more complicated way =).

That said, it's also a good exercise to figure out how you'd determine the resulting polynomials in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ if you weren't given them.

Let $a=x+y+z,b=x^2+y^2+z^2,c=x^3+y^3+z^3$.
We have $xy+xz+yz=\dfrac{a^2-b}2=-1$ and $xyz=\dfrac{a^3+2c-3ab}6=-2$.
\begin{align}(n-x)(n-y)(n-z)&=n^3-n^2(x+y+z)+n(xy+xz+yz)-xyz\\
&=n^3-2n^2-n+2\\
&=(n-2)(n-1)(n+1)\end{align}
so $x,y,z$ must be $2,1,-1$ in some order.
Note $2+1+(-1)=2,2^2+1^2+(-1)^2=6,2^3+1^3+(-1)^3=8$ so $\{x,y,z\}=\{2,1,-1\}$ is the unique solution.
